# Git: get changes with single command

Tags: git

Everytime we deploy code, I need to get the new commits on stage, that are not in master. I use the following commands to achieve that:

```
git merge-base dev master
```

which returns me a commit hash were both branches "split", and then I input that hash into this command:

```
git log commit_hash..HEAD --pretty=oneline --format="%s" | grep -v "Merge pull request"
```

I tried to join both commands, but without success. Is there anyway to achieve that with a single git (or bash) command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just nesting instructions with the `$()` bash construct?

```
git log $(git merge-base dev master)..HEAD --pretty=oneline --format="%s" | grep -v "Merge pull request"
```

It's a single line, but would it fit your definition of "in a single command"?

Comment: Weird ... I did tried to use that, but didn't worked. Well, I probably had some typo in my attempts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this (note tree dots):

```
git log --right-only master...HEAD --pretty=oneline --format="%s" --no-merges
```

See [git log documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for:

- `--right-only`
- `--no-merges`